# how to return something when there is not match in flex(lexer)

Tags: flex-lexer

I am using flex(the lexer) to do some lexical analysis.

What I need is:

If none of the rules are matched, then a value is returned to indicate such thing has happened.

This is like the `default` syntax in the `switch` control flow structure in many programming language.

Is there a way to do such kind of stuff?

**EDIT 1:**
Reference from [the official doc](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Matching.html)

```
If no match is found, then the default rule is executed: 
the next character in the input is considered matched and copied to the standard output.
```

But how can I change the default rule?

Answer (score 1):

In [acacia-lex](http://code.google.com/p/acacia-lex/) it is done in the following way:
Lexer has run method:

@Override

public void run() {

```
Token token;
while ((token = this.findNext()).isFound()) {
    System.out.println("LEXER RES = " + token.toString());

}
```

}

When nothing is found, there is no default rule. Lexer method run just completed its job. 
To continue lexing, at the end of tokens specification is needed token "DOT" -> ".". So if no other tokens match, DOT will match and Lexer run will continue its job.

Answer (score 0):

The default rule only applies if no other rule matches. So you can simply insert your own rule which matches any single character as the last rule:

```
.|\n  {  /* Your default action. */ }
```

It must go at the end because (F)lex will give priority to earlier rules in the file which have the same match. You need to explicitly mention `\n` (unless you are certain that some other rule will match it) because in (F)lex, `.` matches any character *except* a newline.

If you are using Flex, and you don't want the default rule to ever be used, it is advisable to put

```
%option nodefault
```

into your prologue. That will suppress the default rule and produce a warning if there is some input which might not match any rule. (If you ignore the warning, a runtime error will  be produced for such input.)